# "Advertising" vs. "Advertisement" in US political commercials

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

This is the first year I noticed the verbal boilerplate at the end of US political commercials states:

> Group X is responsible for the content of this advertising.

compared to what I recall (and prefer) from previous years,

> Group X is responsible for the content of this advertisement.

I understand **advertisements** to be the end result of **advertising** ([supported here](http://www.emgeepublishing.com/Sample-Chapters/Advertology-chapter%201.pdf)) - and my second example *feels/sounds* more right to me than the first.

However, I also found a number of definitions similar to the second definition on [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/advertising?x=0&y=0): *paid announcements; advertisements* suggesting the two words are completely interchangeable.

Is this a result of some crusade in the *advertising* business to change terminology, a result of the plurality of the times the *advertisement* is run, or am I just being overly picky and I need to get over my distinct preference for **advertisement**?

Comment: They are interchangeable. Both are used as nouns. If there's any distinction between the two, it's that *advertising* (in this case) is a mass noun, but I don't think that has any effect on the legal side (IANAL). In both sentences, it is *this* ad. An advertising campaign may have multiple advertisements, but *this* draws attention to a particular ad, not necessarily the ad campaign as a whole.

Comment: @Zairja, good points. I believe my preference (and frustration) stems from the use of the mass noun when speaking of *this* ad. While *advertising* can also be a verb, *advertisement* is always a noun - a simpler, clearer use, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that in this instance, "advertising" is still valid because while your seeing/listening to their (often ridiculous & outright false) advertisement, they're still responsible for the advertising that the given advertisement is a part of.

Comment: Thanks - I agree it's *valid*.  I just think it's the less clear choice and was hoping I'd get either some validation for my perspective or evidence to counter it.

Comment: I think it's really a matter of opinion. Although, I prefer the "this advertisement" variation as well; it's more specific. Is it any surprise that politicians have been opting for the more ambiguous wording though? :-P